# Write multiple TXT files to Excel in R

Tags: r, xlsx, read.table

I have over 100 txt files that were the output of a SQL scrape across 100 different schemas and tables. The files as tabular data, pipe delimited.
All of the column names in each text file are different.

Once I loaded the files into a directory I created 3 different symbols to separate the files based upon their name. E.g., x.files <- list.files(pattern="_X.txt") so I can separate my "X" files from my other files.

After that I used lapply to loop through those files and "read.csv" them into variable: x.read <- lapply(x.files, read.csv, sep = "|", header = TRUE).

What I need to do now is to write all of those dataframes (stored in a list) back to an XLSX file with a sheet for each dataframe. The preference would be that these TXT files would represent a worksheet for [i] text files within a single workbook (XLSX file).

I'm having some issues doing this using the 'xlsx' and 'XLConnect' packages. They both caused JVM to run out of memory even when I allocate java.parameters to -Xmx4000m.

I've tried using 'openxlsx' but I'm having a difficult time figuring out how to get it to create a sheet based upon the index of the list/df. So, index [1] would be "Sheet 1" and so forth. Or, it would also be fine if the sheet name was the name of the actual file name (SOME_DATA_STORE_SYS_NAME) minus .TXT as the file names are(SOME_DATA_STORE_SYS_NAME.X.txt or .P1.txt, etc).

Comment: Take a look to the [`xlsx` package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/xlsx/)

Comment: I've loaded that package but I don't see anyway that it can write multiple TXT files to multiple sheets in an XLSX doc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a very simple version of an Excel write out function I use frequently. Note, your list names must be unique or this will write over sheets. This may not be a tenable solution if your data frames are very large.

Solution 1 uses the `xlsx` package to build an Excel workbook into your computer's memory and then write all of the sheets simultaneously.

```
require(xlsx)
eg <- list("one" = data.frame(one = rep(1, 100)),
           "two" = data.frame(two = rep(2, 200)))
wb <- createWorkbook()
for (i in seq_along(eg)) {
  sheet <- createSheet(wb, names(eg)[i])
  addDataFrame(eg[i], sheet)
}
saveWorkbook(wb, "eg.xlsx")
```

Solution 2 uses the `XLConnect` package and will write data frames into an Excel worksheet one at a time (with less onerous requirements on your computer's memory).

```
require(XLConnect)
eg <- list("one" = data.frame(one = rep(1, 100)),
           "two" = data.frame(two = rep(2, 200)))
for (i in seq_along(eg)) {
  writeWorksheetToFile(file = "eg.xlsx", data = eg[i], sheet = names(eg)[i])
}
```

Comment: Apologies but I don't get what you're doing there. What is "one" / "two" ? I have a list of dataframes (x.read). It is a large list of 44 elements sized 221Mb.

Comment: @Zach - `eg` is an example list containing two data frames. The list contents are named (the first object is named "one" and the second is named "two"), but these could just as well be the data frames in the list you are describing. If your list does not have named indices, you can just use the value of `i` to name your sheet (as in, `sheet <- createSheet(wb, paste("Sheet", i))`).

Comment: Thanks @ElizabethAB -- Interesting! I'll test this out on Monday and see how it flows. Does I need to explicitly call each dataframe of the list as you have indicated there? Also, what is the purpose of the re(1, 100)..bit?

Comment: @Zach, the section where I generate the `eg` list object (including populating two data frames with 1s and 2s repeated) is only to provide an example. By replacing `eg` with your own list of data frames, this will write them all to the same workbook.

Comment: I tried the script and I keep getting JavaVM and memory heap errors. I increased the memory from 100mb to 2000mb but that didn't seem to help.
Loading required package: xlsx
Loading required package: rJava
Loading required package: xlsxjars
Error in .jcall("RJavaTools", "Ljava/lang/Object;", "newInstance", .jfindClass(class),  : 
  java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Comment: @Zach, see my edited solution for an alternative package that will use less memory.

Comment: The java virtual machine bit is really confounding this whole thing. Initially it was working just fine and writing out but the machine ran out of memory again. I think I'm going to have to try with 'openxlsx'.

Comment: Turns out your version wasn't working correctly. Likely not because of any fault of your own. The Excel workbook had sheet names of: x.read, names(eg), NA. So it created three sheets and then crashed.